# how to create separate error logs for separate virtual hosts

Tags: apache2

I have two virtual hosts on my server pointing towards two separate rails applications. I wanted to create two separate error.log files for each application. I tried to set ErrorLog directive within VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo2.questionscube.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/site-git/html_data
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/site-git/html_data>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-error.log
    </Directory>
```

But it gives an error saying

```
ErrorLog not allowed here
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the ErrorLog directive in the VirtualHost, not Directory section.

See [virtual host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost)